# Rewrite data in a MySQL table in PHP using a primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a chatbot in PHP and the objective is for an employee to change his password in a database using his Employee Id,  I have a database table which has columns
Employee Id(1768,
1347,
1966,
1344)
Password(abc,
def,
ijk,
lmn)

So i want to use Employee Id as primary key to identify whose employee's password i want to change, and then i want to rewrite the data in password column. What is the exact query to achieve that and how could i achieve that in PHP ?
Plus I also want to save the password in encrypted form in the database

Comment: The code you would need to use should not be much different from the code you already have which handles new account (username/password) creations.  You might want to include this code in your question.

Comment: Can you show your existing code that you have tried? And can you tell us are you using the PHP framework or do you used core PHP?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that employee_id is the primary key. Employee_id_value can be replaced as your value in below code:

```
UPDATE employee SET password = new_password 
WHERE employee_id = Employee_id_value
```